# Using closure for counting inside a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried this and it always show 1 time, something's wrong, how to fix this ?

```
    function myFunc() {

        var increment = (function() {
          var i = 0;
        
          return function() {
            i++;
            return i;
          };
        })();
        
        alert(`calling myFunc ${increment()} times`);

    }
```

Comment: Well you only call it once.... Do you call myFunc() multiple times? If yes, you redeclare the method increment  every time....

Comment: of course I call it multiple times :)
but then you say it's impossible to use closure for that use case ?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you call my func it's going to redefine the increment function, so you shouldn't expect it to ever say anything other than `1`. Your problem is that increment is being defined on every call to `myFunc`

What you want to do is this:

```
var i = 0;
function myFunc() {
    var increment = (function() {
        return function() {
            i++;
            return i;
        };
    })();
        
    alert(`calling myFunc ${increment()} times`);
}
```

So now `i` will keep its values between calls to `myFunc`. It'll have to be outside `myFunc`. Or you can move the whole function outside of `myFunc`.

```
var increment = (function() {
    var i = 0;
        
    return function() {
        i++;
        return i;
    };
})();
function myFunc() {
    alert(`calling myFunc ${increment()} times`);
}
```

Now this works:

```
console.log(increment()); // logs 1
console.log(increment()); // logs 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when a variable goes out of scope it is destroyed, the next time a value is called it will be recreated, and initialized at whatever value it starts as. As the variable `i` is scoped to inside the `increment` function, which is itself scoped to `myFunc` it means that when `myFunc` that closure is destroyed and will be created the next time the function is run.

An example that shows `i` hoisted to be in `myFunc`'s scope and the `increment` function running several times.

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log('running myFunc');
  var i = 0;
  console.log('assigning i to ' + i);

  function increment() {
    console.log('incrementing');
    i++;
  };
  increment();
  increment();
  console.log(`calling myFunc ${i} times`);
}

myFunc();
```

Notice that `i` now maintains its state across calls to `increment`. Now when we call `myFunc` multiple times, we see that `i` is destroyed, then a new variable is created when `myFunc` is run again.

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log('running myFunc');
  var i = 0;
  console.log('assigning i to ' + i);

  function increment() {
    console.log('incrementing');
    i++;
  }
  increment();
  increment();
  console.log(`calling myFunc ${i} times`);
}

myFunc();
myFunc();
```

Now if we hoist `i` up to be above the scope of `myFunc` we'll see that it's value is kept within scope across calls to `myFunc`.

```js
var i = 0;
console.log('assigning i to ' + i);

function myFunc() {
  console.log('running myFunc');

  function increment() {
    console.log('incrementing');
    i++;
  }
  increment();
  console.log(`calling myFunc ${i} times`);
}

myFunc();
myFunc();
```

Comment: OK that's the right answer but if I hoist i outside of myFunc then it becomes global, what I wanted is that it stays local to myFunc. Let's says I have myFunc1, myFunc2, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```js
var increment = (function() {
  var i = 0;

  return function() {
    i++;
    return i;
  };
})();

console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
```

Comment: `const increment = (i => () => ++i)(0);`

Comment: This works because it isn't inside another function like the OP posted, misses the point of why it's not working for him